Trying to use GTMAppAuth in objectiveC project using cocoapods throws errors
I'm trying to use GTMAppAuth in my ObjectiveC project.
In my podfile I use pod 'GTMAppAuth' platform: ios, '12.0' and use_frameworks!
The Podfile seems to be installed and I can see the GTMAppAuth in my Pods, too.
But when I try #import <GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth.h> I'm getting an error saying #import <GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuth.h> file not found.
Same goes for #import <GTMAppAuth/GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization.h>.
What am I doing wrong?

use more modern syntax for importing modules @import GTMAppAuth;

Thanks, that sort of works. Seems  like there are lots of deprecations in newser versions of GoogleSignIn. I get weird errors (handleUrl not working, for example). Do you have an idea where I find the latest examples for GIDSignIn?
